# Return a Bitmap using Async Task

Tags: c#, android, bitmap, android-asynctask, xamarin

I am using Xamarin and I am wanting to get many Bitmaps from different urls when my app is running. I have done some research, and have found that I need to use an Async Task.

May I please have some help to write this code?

I have the following code in Java, however, I am having trouble converting this to C#:

```
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       URL myurl = new URL(params[0]); 
       Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(myurl.OpenConnection().InputStream);
       return bmp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        item.icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBitmap(bmp);
        item.Location = new LatLng (-41.227834, 174.812857);
        item.Snippet = "Snippet2";
        item.Title = "Title2";
        item.ShowInfoWindowOnStartup = true;
        _mapLocationList.Add(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

Also, how do I call the code to retrieve the Bitmap?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Basically, I have many image files that are online and I wish to retrieve these files and store them each in a Bitmap.

An error occurs if I use the main thread.

How is the best way to get these image files and store them in a Bitmap objects?

Comment: If you want to duplicate it then have you started with 'internal class LoadImage : AsyncTask<String, long, Bitmap>'? I would go with Sebastian's approach though as it is better many times to do things the C# way rather than refactor Java code.

Answer (score 0):

```
new LoadImage.execute("Your string paramters");
```

The execute method calls the doInBackground etc.

Comment: @user22707 Sorry I dont know C# >.<

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific enough for a real answer. Apparently you want to download an image without blocking the thread. Using Tasks or the C# async / await keywords is not required for this. Or is your intention actually to download many image in parallel as fast as possible?

Starting DownloadDataAsync after registering the event will immediately continue with the next statements, while at a point later in time the method DownloadComplete will be invoked
and your Image becomes available

```
    public static void BeginDownload()
    {
        var wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadComplete;
        wc.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://www......"));
        ...
    }

    private static void DownloadComplete(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(args.Result))
        {
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            // At this point you have the image downloaded and available
        }
    }
```